# What's the accuracy of these sentences?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, lexicon

Could you guys tell me if these sentences are ok?

1) I graduated, in 2014, as a Industrial Designer;

2) This area of work brings me to achieve, every day, technical and mental skills improvements.
I visualize that as a challenge, for which, I can provide with a new strength for the company, to reach the needs of common goals.

3) Developing and improving my skills are goals that I would like to achieve with your team and most of all, collaborate at Yours projects, 
which have a high level of professionalism and they are an inspiration for me.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. **Proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Are there any mistakes?")** or critique requests are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

> - I graduated in 2014 with a degree in industrial design.
> - I am always striving to improve my technical and mental skills. In so doing, I believe I can be a strong link in achieving the company's goals.
> - I am inspired both to collaborate with a team of professionals on completing whatever projects we are assigned and to become a valuable asset to your design team as I develop and improve my skills.